# Manipulate a key value pair to a string in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I need some help in manipulating a value pair array to return a string in a specific layout
This is the string i am trying to achieve:

```
'&test=id:1111|na:shoes|ca:shoe&test=id:2222|na:top|ca:tops'
```

This is the array I am trying to manipulate into my string

```
var prodlist = 
[
    {
        name: 'shoe',
        sku: '1111',
        category: 'shoes'
    },
    {
        name: 'top',
        sku: '2222',
        category: 'tops'
    }
]
```

Here is what I have tried.

I added the 'deleteme' into the array thinking i could to a substitute later down the script.

```
function(){ 
    var prods = prodlist;
    var array = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < prods.length; i++) {
        var sku = (prods[i]['sku']);
        var name = (prods[i]['name']);
        var cat = (prods[i]['category']);

        array.push({
            deleteme: &test=id,
            id: sku,
            na: name,
            ca: cat,
        });
    }
    var newarray = array.toString();
    return newarray;
}
```

At the moment this function returns '[object Object],[object Object]'

any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: You are pushing objects into the array and calling the *toString* method of the array. That will also call the objects' [*toString*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-object.prototype.tostring) which returns "[object Object]". You should be pushing strings into the array, not objects, e.g. `array.push('&test=id' + sku + '|na:' + name + ...)`. Then use `join.('')` instead of *toString* or the strings will be joined with the default comma.

Comment: @RobG You're exactly right... That was perfect! Thanks so much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quick and easy

```
function prods() {
     var prods = prodlist;
     var array = [];
     for (let product of prods)
        array.push('test=id:' + product.sku+ '|na:' + product.name + '|ca:' + product.category);
     return '&' + array.join('&');
}
```

Comment: Why not put the `'&'` directly in the string that you `.push()`? (And then `join('')`)

Comment: @nnnnnn Good point, that would work perfectly.  Performance wise it doesn't really matter to my knowledge.

Comment: Yeah, it doesn't actually *matter*, it would just make for a slightly neater return statement.

Answer (score 1):

how about something like this?

```
var prodlist = 
[{name: 'shoe',
sku: '1111',
 category: 'shoes'},
 {name: 'top',
 sku: '2222',
 category: 'tops'}]

var strTemplate = "&test=id:%sku%|na:%name%|ca:%category%"

prodlist.map( function(obj){
   return strTemplate.replace(/%(\w+)%/g, function($1, $2) {
     return obj[$2]
   })
}).join('')

//returns
// "&test=id:1111|na:shoe|ca:shoes&test=id:2222|na:top|ca:tops"
```

or ES6 version (edited it down further as suggested by nnnnnn )

```
prodlist.map( obj => strTemplate.replace(/%(\w+)%/g, ($1, $2) => obj[$2])).join('')
```

Comment: Or compact ES6 (without the `return` and `{}`): `prodlist.map( obj => strTemplate.replace(/%(\w+)%/g, ($1, $2) => obj[$2])).join('')`.

Comment: u are correct, I was in a rush.. let me correct it. good catch! :-)

Comment: P.S.: I forgot to say nice use of `.replace()`. +1.